# How to make the index go in countdown fashion in a map() loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

This:

```
Array(12).fill().map((_, i) => {
  console.log(i)
})
```

Produces this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

How to change the loop so I get:

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

EDIT: I tried this:

```
Array(12).fill().reverse().map((_, i)
```

But I'm still getting the index in the same order.

Comment: Why are you using `.map()` for mere looping? You're building an array of `undefined` and throwing it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try subtracting the index from length of the array like this:

```js
const array = Array(12).fill()
array.map((_, j) => {
  console.log(array.length - j - 1)
})
```

Or this:

```js
Array(12).fill().map((_, i, array) => {
  console.log(array.length - i - 1)
})
```